# winCE C# HttpWebresponse timeout

Tags: c#, http, httprequest, windows-ce, httpresponse

I'm programming a Windows CE 6 device and want to make a request on a local Server! The device and the Server are in the same Wireless Network.

The device tries to perform a `getresquest()` on the Server.

```
public int test()
{
    string var1 = "whatever";
    req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.create("http://192.168.x.x/test.php?var1=" + var1);
```

The `requesttimeout` is set to 1 second.

```
req.Timeout = 1000;
```

Then I Try to get a response:

```
try
{
    res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
}

catch(Exception e)
{
    //What happens if an exception occures
}
```

My big problem is that  the request sometimes times out but send the data to the server! Is there a possiblity to check if the data was transfer to the server or not?

Comment: my fault: req.Timeout = 1000;

Comment: why do you set such a small integer timeout ? if you want asynchronuous requests use class instances on push and pop list which blocks until data is received or a timeout is hit

Comment: I need a high frequency of requests. so the longest response time should be not longer 1500 ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timeout applies to the time required to send the request and get a response back from server. In that case it seems that send has been completed and timeout happens when your client is waiting for the response.

Comment: This is exactly my Problem. Is there a way I can sove it?